# How to convert a file:// uri into content:// uri?

Tags: android, uri

I have found that on my device, the default media display tool is not showing me the same if Ihave a uri that is:

```
file://mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Image.jpg
```

When I go through picking the image with the built in intent I get this:

```
content://media/external/images/media/247
```

These both display the same file, but I don't have any sharing options when I use the first one.

My question is, how can I find the content Uri given the file Uri?

Comment: I have the reverse question -- I have the content uri from insertImage and I need a File-url.

Comment: @Richard ask it as a new question, otherwise you're only getting my attention.

Comment: Thanks; found it through further searching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was making the file, so I had a `File` object `file`.

So I do this now to get Uri for the file as a "content://" Uri.

```
Uri capturedImage = Uri.parse(
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
      getContentResolver(),
      file.getAbsolutePath(), null, null));
```

Credit to answer on this question [How can I capture an image in Android and have it show up in the gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567732/how-can-i-capture-an-image-in-android-and-have-it-show-up-in-the-gallery)

Comment: @tejshah It's customary to click the grey up arrow to show appreciation for a useful answer :)