# convert url from sdcard to content uri

Tags: android, uri

i want to bypass Intent.ACTION_PICK to do so i need to insert content uri but i have string with url.

**i need to convert this format :**

```
 /mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4
```

**to uri  format  :**

```
content://media/external/video/media/2308
```

i find this :

[How to convert a file:// uri into content:// uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150924/i-have-a-file-uri-but-i-want-a-content-uri)

and this to image
[Convert file uri to content uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305504/convert-file-uri-to-content-uri)

***update :***

I have a method that send file, this method gets content uri.

so to use this method i'm using intent because the output is content uri.

i'm using this intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK_IMAGE_CROP);
```

this intent open folder, the user pick folder and after video file

my previous Q :
[intent ACTION_PICK in specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305559/intent-action-pick-in-specific-folder)

the problem is that i need just specific folder , but i red here

[Using Intent.ACTION_PICK for specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486716/using-intent-action-pick-for-specific-path)

this is not possible.

so i try to convert The path that I have to content url

Comment: You can use [ Uri.parse(fileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

Snippet:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4"))
```

or

```
Uri.parse(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4").toString())
```

Comment: i recive file:///mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4 not this format content://media/external/video/media/2308

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("%PATH_TO_FILE%/test.mp4");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

That will open the file with the default video player bypassing the choice

You can get a content URI from a file like this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg"));
```

or like this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString());
```

That should give you a Uri you can use

Reference: [Get content uri from file path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: i try this but i dont know why not work                           Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
     //startActivity(intent);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK_IMAGE_CROP);

Comment: What is RESULT_PICK_IMAGE_CROP? is that a mask you have set yourself? I haven't heard of it

Comment: it just final int like 4 , in the result i have switch. in the result FileURI = data.getData();

Comment: Are you sure the application you are trying to launch with will return a result? What errors are you getting. It is hard to be helpful without things like Logcats to see what is actually happening. It could be a number of things. Is there definitely an MP4 compatible video player. Does the video file definitely exist? Also, what are you trying to do with this video having named the flag RESULT_PICK_IMAGE_CROP

Comment: Have updated my answer on how to get a content Uri from a file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29601/discussion-between-o0rebelious0o-and-idan)