# how to convert this uri file://mnt/ to this uri content://media

Tags: android, uri, mime-types, content-type

I posted a similar question, but I have not received an answer that solves the problem.

[convert url from sdcard to content uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440191/convert-url-from-sdcard-to-content-uri)

i need simple code that convert this format:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice080513_141510.mp4 not this forma content://media/external/video/media/2308
```

to this format :

```
content://media/external/video/media/2308
```

i saw those related Q :
[How to convert a file:// uri into content:// uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150924/i-have-a-file-uri-but-i-want-a-content-uri)

in the oposit side
[Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri?rq=1)

Comment: Try using [MediaStore.Video.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Media.html).getContentUri (String volumeName)